# `ConnectionClosed` when using `getObject` from amazonka-s3

Tags: haskell, amazon-s3, conduit

I have a function

```
import Control.Lens ((^.))
import Data.Conduit (sinkLazy)
import Network.AWS (MonadAWS, send, sinkBody)
import Network.AWS.S3 (BucketName (..), ObjectKey (..), gorsBody, getObject)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS


getObjectData :: MonadAWS m => Text -> Text -> m LBS.ByteString
getObjectData b k = do
  resp <- send $ getObject (BucketName b) (ObjectKey k)
  (resp ^. gorsBody) `sinkBody` sinkLazy
```

whose purpose is to get the data from some object on s3 into a lazy bytestring.

Sending the request is successful, and I can see the response.  Of course, the `gorsBody` field is shown as `RsBody { ConduitM () ByteString (ResourceT IO) () }` because that is what it is.

When I try the last line of the function, I get something like this:

```
*** Exception: HttpExceptionRequest Request {
  host                 = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  port                 = 443
  secure               = True
  requestHeaders       = [("Host","s3.amazonaws.com"),("X-Amz-Date","20181121T001938Z"),("X-Amz-Content-SHA256","blah"),("X-Amz-Security-Token","blah"),("Authorization","<REDACTED>")]
  path                 = "/path/to/my/file.txt"
  queryString          = ""
  method               = "GET"
  proxy                = Nothing
  rawBody              = False
  redirectCount        = 0
  responseTimeout      = ResponseTimeoutMicro 70000000
  requestVersion       = HTTP/1.1
}
 ConnectionClosed
```

It sort of seems like this might have something to do with laziness; maybe that the response body was never evaluated before the connection was closed.  But that's pure speculation, and in any case, I am not sure how to address it.  Does anyone have an idea of what is happening here?  It seems like what I'm doing is the right use of amazonka-s3+conduit.

I'm using `lts-11.14` and `amazonka-s3-1.6.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/brendanhay/amazonka/issues/466) with the Stackage release of `amazonka-s3`, which hasn't been fixed yet.  The workaround is to upgrade the amazonka/core/s3 dependencies to point to a fixed version of master:

```
# stack.yaml
extra-deps:
- git: git@github.com:brendanhay/amazonka
  commit: 248f7b2a7248222cc21cef6194cd1872ba99ac5d
  subdirs:
    - amazonka
    - core
    - amazonka-s3
```

Comment: Have you tried using this hash? I'm running into the same bug even with the hash you mentioned.

Comment: @Ashesh 248f7b2a7248222cc21cef6194cd1872ba99ac5d is indeed the commit hash that works for me.

Comment: Stupid suggestion, but have you tried a `stack clean && rm -rf .stack-work/ && stack build`?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me. It was my bad: I was doing `runResourceT` before consuming the response body.

Comment: I was doing the same thing as @ashesh - running `runResourceT` meant I was releasing a resource before it was consumed.